# how do i display google search result in a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

am working with WordPress 4.8.2 and Sahifa theme

How do i display google search results in a page?

I want to display category achieve page as search results page.

example

[http://www.wejobz.com/latest-accountant-jobs-in-dubai/?cx=partner-pub-5102448773014275%3A8327363392&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=accounting+jobs+in+dubai](http://www.wejobz.com/latest-accountant-jobs-in-dubai/?cx=partner-pub-5102448773014275%3A8327363392&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=accounting%20jobs%20in%20dubai)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a Custom Search Engine from google. You can build your own with [google's CSE](https://cse.google.com/cse/).

Comment: I did, but only search console is appearing. I need to display results.

Comment: Look at their source code, search for googleSearchFrame. You'll find an iframe with the URL like `http://www.google.ae/cse?cx=partner-pub-....`. Copy that URL, use your own partner-credentials and put it in an iframe on your site.

Comment: am sorry, where do i get this google search frame?
I've gone through the code but couldn't find any.

Comment: Ah, I looked at the DOM, not the source. It's probably injected with JavaScript, search for `cse-search-results` in the source. Or just try with the [guides by google](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630969?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin 
JSM's file_get_contents() Shortcode , A WordPress shortcode for PHP’s file_get_contents() function.

https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-get-contents/

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)